# NgRX store.select returns store object instead of observable object

Tags: javascript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have written a short example of Ngrx. I had no idea why this short code could not run properly.

```
constructor(private store: Store<CounterState>){
this.counter = store.select('counter');
console.log(this.counter);
}
```

This piece of code prints a Store object to the console instead of an observable. It is weird.
The full version of the app please follow the link below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dq7ssf

Comment: Recently with the appearance of rxjs v6, do something like this this.counter = store.pipe(select('counter'));  Also check demo app on the repo on github for more inside. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the example you posted you're defining the rootstate with:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({  counterReducer })
```

Meaning that `counterReducer` is the key to access your counter state, to solve this you can select the counter as follows

```
this.counter = store.select('counterReducer', 'counter');
```

Or you could give your reducer a key:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({  counter: counterReducer });
this.counter = store.select('counter', 'counter');
```

Answer (score 1):

In the post, when your writing **store.select('counter')**, it will return an observable and you assigned that to a property "counter".Now, the "counter" property also became an observable.To retrieve values from an observable, you need subscribe it.The below code will solve your problem.

//Rxjs 5 way

```
this.counter.subscribe(
(data:any) => {

console.log(data) //your data shows here
});
```

//Rxjs 6 way, with pipe operator

```
this.counter.pipe().subscribe(
(data:any) => {

console.log(data) //your data shows here
});
```

I hope, my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a look at the [Ngrx Store Source](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/store.ts), `Store` *is* an `Observable`!

```
export class Store<T> extends Observable<T> implements Observer<Action> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: how is this helpful?